# In ngx-datatable, Is it possible to sort by the value of a the check box column?

Tags: ngx-datatable

I am leveraging ngx-datatable in an Angular application and am using the built in selection features. One of the requirements is the ability to sort by things that are selected either in descending (true -> false) or ascending fashion.

Is this possible in this component?

I've looked at the documentation and the demos and don't see an example. I've tried making that column sortable with [sortable]="true", but that doesn't seem to add the arrow buttons necessary to provide a sort.

My current thinking is to write a handler for the (select) event.
That will give me an array of things selected. I can then mark all my items with a 1 or a zero in a selected property and sort on that with a custom comparator function as described here: https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs#comparator

As I am writing it this seems complicated and hacky so I feel there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry Fintan, this functionality was deemed a "nice-to-have" from the business so I moved on without having to address this.